# db design for ad delivery

Tags: sql, database-design

i am building an ad delivery system similar to the one on facebook.. Basically my clients can create adverts and target them to particular members, based on location and bio data that we will constantly collect from them.

at the moment it is designed as so..

```
member
-----
id 
fname
lname
country_id
state_id
region_id
postcode_id
etc..
```

I know i only need the postcodeid and the look it up in the postcode table.. but i have around 50 postcode tables one for each country.. just easier for me..

```
member_profile
-----
id
mem_id
bio_q (id linked to varchar .. eg. 'profession')
bio_a

advert
-------
id
client_id
ad_title
ad_line
start_date
end_date
status
etc..

advert_target
-----
id
advert_id
fk_id
type
```

eg data for above..

```
1, 1, 1, 'state'
2, 1, 2, 'state'
3, 1, 5, 'profession'
```

one way i though of doing it is by doing a whole heap of union statements... not sure if this the most effecient way.. any help with direction would be greatly appreciated..

thanks

a

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: just asking for help on database design for this type of system

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this kind of application introduces the concept of "segment", assigns users to segments, and targets ads at segments.

So, you might assign a given user to 5 segments "lives in Europe", "lives in Italy", "lives in Rome", "lives within 5 kilometers of postcode x", "is at least 18 years old",

You then might have ads targeting segments "lives in Italy", "is at least 18 years old", "has visited the site at least 3 times"; our sample user score 2 out of 3 criteria, so might only be shown ads if noboy more qualified turns up.

You want to pre-populate your segments in regular database jobs; doing this on the fly will cripple your system with even moderate levels of traffic.

Comment: question.. is this how you think facebook does it with their system? I am starting to think i may have to limit my clients to say 5 bio questions.. Would turning my advert table into a pivot.. be better?

Comment: Not sure how FB does their stuff - but you prob. don't want to replicate what they do, as they have problems you may never face. Have a look at this Open Source ad server - http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpadsnew/, and poke around in their database schema for inspiration...

Comment: thanks for your help... i decided to run a simulator with 300,000 records and ran a simple union script to get the ads based on location.. it was really slow until i indexed the impressions column..around 2ms.. hopefully it will hold up under lots of traffic..